# Will I see a performance improvement migrating an Access-based VBA tool to a standalone .Net application?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, vba

I understand this is dependent on the application. The tool in question iterates over a fixed width text file and checks against a set of validation rules specified in an Access table. Running a standard file through all validation checks may take up to an hour using the current tool.

I could migrate the validation rule tables into SQL Server and refactor the code into a standalone VB.Net application.

Is there a reason I should expect to see performance improvements?

Comment: How big is the file that takes an hour to process? How many validation rules?

Comment: How much time is spent in Access versus how much time is spent processing the file?   How big is the validation rules.  Why not just load them once into a .NET collection.  A Dictionary look up is even faster than SQL.

Comment: How large is the file? What do the rules look like? What in specific is taking long time? It will be difficult to answer without seeing some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on so many things, not least the developer. I always think that a good developer with poor technology can produce a better product than a poor developer with cutting edge technology.

There are many variables which matter in making a decision to migrate. For example:

- Is you current database running on a server or a local machine? I've worked for big companies who have servers which are always running out of space. This can really slow down performance. Running locally with lots of memory will always be faster.
- When you run these rules, do the tables get used in queries or in code? Is it optimised? Are there many levels of queries which it has to go through. Try cutting them down.
- If there is lots of VBA in the database, try putting lots of debug.print in the code with a timer on it so you can see what parts of the process are running fast\slow.
- Is there anyone accessing the database while it's running?
- Do you need to index the tables? Sometimes too much indexing can affect performance especially if it's not required.
- Maybe you can try normalising elements of your file when it's imported and then run the rules.
- If the database isn't currently split into a Front End - Back End, try splitting it. Maybe it's too big (compact and repair).

As you mentioned in your post, there are many variables at stake so I wouldn't rush into a migration. Trust me, I've seen it before and there is no guarantee you will get a significant improvement without careful analysis of your current situation.

One other thing you could consider rather than migrating, is automation. I worked in a RAD team which ran lots of early morning processes. We simply used Windows Scheduled Tasks to fire up a database at some specific time, search and import files, and then process them. Some processes may have taken a hour but they were all done before we got into the office in the morning so who cares if it took an hour so long as it was complete.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Specifically the idea of using Windows Scheduled Tasks. One more question... what do you mean by normalizing elements of your file when it's imported?

Comment: Chances are there may be a lot of repetition in the columns of the file you're importing. By normalising a table you can eliminate redundancy & repetition in the tables, and make fields 'atomic' (only 1 piece of data in a cell).  There's actually a lot more to it thank that.
E.g. when you import the file, if there are any columns with lots of duplicate data (e.g users name), you could run some queries to extract the values & stick them in a joining with an id. Then replace the name with that id.
That's very short & simplistic answer I know, but worth having a read for future reference anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the real answer is "It depends..." but I would venture a guess that, based on the type of processing you've described, I wouldn't expect to see a large performance difference between doing that sort of work in Access VBA and doing the same type of work in a standalone .NET app.

Switching the back-end database from ACE/Jet to SQL Server *could* yield some significant performance benefits depending on the volume of data involved and whether some of the validations could be pushed down from the application level (VBA or .NET) to the database level (SQL Server). However, moving the back-end to SQL Server does not necessarily **require** that you completely port the application code from VBA to .NET. Depending on your specific requirements you can have...

- an Access VBA project using ACE/Jet as a back-end,
- an Access VBA project using SQL Server as a back-end (linked tables),
- a .NET application using ACE/Jet as a back-end, or
- a .NET application using SQL Server as a back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Your best chance at a performance increase with .NET will be to pull the rules into memory (perhaps a collection of rule objects) and remove the database bottleneck from the process.

Answer (score -1):

You may see performance improvements if you're repeatedly pulling up the rules from the Access table, but it's likely how you're performing the validation which is causing the performance concerns.  .NET would give you the ability to do parallel operations on the text file, once you've loaded it into memory, which may give you some improvements in performance.  But, if your requirements can be implemented across all rows, then I think that your biggest improvement would probably be to pull the data from the text file into SQL Server implemented in T-SQL, which is optimized for operating on entire sets of data, rather than row-by-row. or implement them from an external tool (.NET will be faster than VBA, yes).

If you can't / don't want to pull the text file into SQL, consider that in .NET you can pull that file into memory & manipulate it using multi-threaded loops, testing against your rules.  There's a limit to how many threads will be beneficial, of course, but if you've got 4 processors, you might as well use them.

Comment: You think the validation he is performing in vb.net can be preformed in TSQL?   TSQL is for searching not validating text.  TSQL string functions are very limited compared to .NET.

Comment: Since he doesn't specify *what* he's validating in .NET, well, yes, I do think he can perform those validations in T-SQL.  As to the functions being more limited as compared to .NET - I think that there are quite a few things which can be easily done in SQL (think: searching for certain strings and discarding those rows) which are just what a database engine is built to do.  Also, if the data is fixed-width, it's likely to fit nicely into a tabular structure, which means that quite a few problematic records could be discarded simply in the bulk loading of the table.

Comment: Really, he is performing validation on a text in VB on your answer is to load that text in SQL and use TSQL.   You would load a rows into SQL to search on them to discard rows rather than just validate a file at a time in VB.   How is deleting a row validation?  There is no requirement to load this file data into the database.

Comment: I think that you're getting distracted by this point, truly.  Thanks for the -1.  Did you even **read** the rest of my suggestion, or are you just prejudiced against using databases?  Nothing in the OP said what sorts of validation, nor what the further requirements are, so I threw out a suggestion.  And now we're down here in the comments, discussing something which may have no import whatsoever to the OP's requirements, because they weren't stated in that level of detail.  Get a life, maybe?

Comment: I am prejudiced by if I have a text in file VB why would you load the file into SQL to validate it in SQL.  It takes time to load a file into SQL. There is not validation I can TSQL that cannot be done faster in .NET.  There is no requirement to load the file into SQL.   I like databases - when I needs a database.